# Playing widevine drm dash url on ios swift

Tags: ios, drm, widevine

I want to play widevine url on ios,is there any player in ios similar to android exoplayer that supports widevine DRM,right now in android i am able to play widevine mpd file

exception:

```
[ERROR:/Developer/playground/google3/third_party/video/widevine/cdm_release/core/src/license.cpp(452)] CdmLicense::HandleKeyResponse: unable to parse signed license response
[ERROR:/Developer/playground/google3/third_party/video/widevine/cdm_release/core/src/cdm_engine.cpp(312)] CdmEngine::AddKey: keys not added, result = 70
[ERROR:/Developer/playground/google3/third_party/video/widevine/cdm_release/cdm/src/cdm.cpp(497)] Unexpected error 70
```

Answer (score 0):

Widevine do have an iOS SDK - you can see them mention it on their update page:

> We had a busy year in 2015 launching new and updated products like the iOS SDK; Shaka Player with offline playback, captioning and cast support; and key security improvements for Chrome and Android. We have a ton of exciting things planned for 2016 and look forward to sharing more details in the coming months!

To get access you need to be part of the partner program, AFAIK - details on the partner program are available on their website:

- https://www.widevine.com/cwip/index.html

Comment: we are already part of the partner program,i got ios sdk code but i need to configure some parameters like license server,widevine uuid,dash mpd url,header

Comment: Yes - those are the standard info you need for widevine DASH playback. If you just need to see how they are used generally then the Google Shaka player demo is a good resource.

Comment: i configured license server and mpd url still i am getting exception keys not added

Comment: Can you provide an example manifest and LA URL and we can check?

Comment: i am getting some exception while using our license server url,mpd